# Strange insecure tracking code loaded on a secure page with https

Tags: security

i have a website running adsense and its on HTTPS

recently i noticed some mixed content warnings. When i checked the insecure content loaded it turned out to be coming from this domain:

http://ad.afy11.net/ad?mode=7&publisher_dsp_id=74&external_user_id=AQECC2tGjY3QXwJlCfSKAQEBAQE&expiration=1526138980&external_user_id=

i read online that this is some tracking code by adsense, but how come it's not secure? other people said it could be a malware, so what exactly is that?

Answer (score 0):

"Mixed content" means that your page is served over HTTPS, but some sub-components are HTTP. This URL begins `http:`.

The primary concern in this case is that this domain name can be spoofed on a local network, causing browsers who have contacted your secure site (and displayed a "this connection is secure" icon in their user) to be tricked into also contacting a malicious site.

It is possible that you've misconfigured AdSense. See [AdSense ad code support for SSL](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10528?hl=en) for instructions. If this is coming from some other provider, then you need to work with them to convert it to HTTPS.